# UVIew in an NSMutableArray

Tags: objective-c, uiview, nsmutablearray

I am struggling to update a UIView in an NSArray. I have created an NSMutableArray and filled it with UIViews. Problem is I cannot update the position of the UViews. What am I doing wrong? Here is my code:

```
for (j = 0; j <200; j++) {
    UIView *currentView = [self.ViewArray objectAtIndex:j];

    [currentView setFrame:CGRectMake(x, y, 20, 20)];
}
```

Comment: Are you in main thread while during this? Are you using constraints?

Comment: Yes. Im in the main thread and there are no constraints.

Comment: Are these views added to any view?

Comment: Yes they are added to the main view with [self.mainview addSubview:view];

Comment: Spynet, won't this code will just create more views? I want to update the views stored in the NSMuatableArray.

Comment: As Obi Wan would say, those are not the views you're looking for.  (I suspect you are mistaken in your belief that those views are visible on the main view.)

Comment: actually what is your need that's not looks clumsy , What is x and y position do you know ? use [self.view setNeedsDisplay]

Comment: Please add the code of how these are being added to the mainview and when you are running this loop?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you add the view on ViewDidLoad method and then you update the view?

Comment: Yes. I have created the array of views in ViewDidLoad but they are not updating in my UpdateViews method with the for loop.

Comment: try creating and adding them to the view within the same method

Comment: yes @FahimParkar answer covers what I am suggesting above

Answer (score 0):

Doesn't `UIView *currentView = [self.ViewArray objectAtIndex:j];` should be `UIView *currentView = (UIView *) [self.ViewArray objectAtIndex:j];`

Could you also show us how you are adding views in array?

*IMO, I don't think you will be able to get views in this way.*

***What you should do is as below.***

```
for (int i=0;i<200;i++) {
    UIView *mView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,0,0,0)];
    mView.tag = 998877 + i;
    [self.view addSubview:mView];
}
```

Now in update view do like below.

```
-(void) updateMyViews {
    for (j = 0; j <200; j++) {
        UIView *currentView = (UIView *) [self.view viewWithTag:998877+j];

        [currentView setFrame:CGRectMake(x, y, 20, 20)];
    }
}
```